# Extracting a string between two similar (or different) strings in C as fast as possible

Tags: c, string, find

I made a program in C that can find two similar or different strings and extract the string between them. This type of program has so many uses, and generally when you use such a program, you have a lot of info, so it needs to be fast. I would like tips on how to make this program as fast and efficient as possible.

I am looking for suggestions that won't make me resort to heavy libraries (such as regex).

The code must:

- be able to extract a string between two similar or different strings
- find the 1st occurrence of `string1`
- find the 1st occurrence of `string2` which occurs AFTER `string1`
- extract the string between `string1` and `string2`
- be able to use string arguments of any size
- be foolproof to human error and return `NULL` if such occurs (example, `string1` exceeds entire text string length. don't crash in an element error, but gracefully return `NULL`)
- focus on speed and efficiency

Below is my code. I am quite new to C, coming from C++, so I could probably use a few suggestions, especially regarding efficient/proper use of the 'malloc' command:

**fast_strbetween.c**:

```
/*
   Compile with:
   gcc -Wall -O3 fast_strbetween.c -o fast_strbetween
*/

#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc

// inline function if it pleases the compiler gods
inline size_t fast_strlen(char *str)
{
    int i;   // Cannot return 'i' if inside for loop
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);

    return i;
}

char *fast_strbetween(char *str, char *str1, char *str2)
{
    // size_t segfaults when incorrect length strings are entered (due to going below 0), so use int instead for increased robustness
    int str0len    = fast_strlen(str);
    int str1len    = fast_strlen(str1);
    int str1pos    = 0;
    int charsfound = 0;

    // Find str1
    do {
        charsfound = 0;

        while (str1[charsfound] == str[str1pos + charsfound])
            ++charsfound; 

    } while (++str1pos < str0len - str1len && charsfound < str1len);

    // '++str1pos' increments past by 1: needs to be set back by one
    --str1pos;

    // Whole string not found or logical impossibilty
    if (charsfound < str1len)
        return NULL;

    /* Start searching 2 characters after last character found in str1. This will ensure that there will be space, and logical possibility, for the extracted text to exist or not, and allow immediate bail if the latter case; str1 cannot possibly have anything between it if str2 is right next to it!

       Example:

       str      = 'aa'
       str1     = 'a'
       str2     = 'a'
       returned = '' (should be NULL)

       Without such preventative, str1 and str2 would would be found and '' would be returned, not NULL. This also saves 1 do/while loop, one check pertaining to returning null, and two additional calculations:

       Example, if you didn't add +1 str2pos, you would need to change the code to:

       if (charsfound < str2len || str2pos - str1pos - str1len < 1)
           return NULL;

       It also allows for text to be found between three similar strings—what??? I can feel my brain going fuzzy!

       Let this example explain:

       str    = 'aaa'
       str1   = 'a'
       str2   = 'a'
       result = '' (should be 'a')

       Without the aforementioned preventative, the returned string is '', not 'a'; the program takes the first 'a' for str1 and the second 'a' for str2, and tries to return what is between them (nothing).

    */
    int str2pos = str1pos + str1len + 1; // the '1' added to str2pos
    int str2len = fast_strlen(str2);

    // Find str2
    do {
        charsfound = 0;

        while (str2[charsfound] == str[str2pos + charsfound])
            ++charsfound;

    } while (++str2pos < str0len - str2len + 1 && charsfound < str2len);

    // Deincrement due to '++str2pos' over-increment
    --str2pos;

    if (charsfound < str2len)
        return NULL;

    // Only allocate what is needed
    char *strbetween = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * str2pos - str1pos - str1len);

    unsigned int tmp = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = str1pos + str1len; i < str2pos; i++)
        strbetween[tmp++] = str[i];

    return strbetween;
}

int main() {
    char str[30] =  { "abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb" };
    char str1[10] = { "aaa" };
    char str2[10] = { "bbb" };

    //Result should be: 'abba' 

    printf("The string between is: \'%s\'\n", fast_strbetween(str, str1, str2));

    // free malloc as we go
    for (int i = 10000000; --i;)
        free(fast_strbetween(str, str1, str2));

    return 0;
}
```

In order to have some way of measuring progress, I have already timed the code above (extracting a small string 10000000 times):

```
$ time fast_strbetween                                                  
The string between is: 'abba'
    0m11.09s real     0m11.09s user     0m00.00s system
```

Process used 99.3 - 100% CPU according to 'top' command (Linux).
Memory used while running: 3.7Mb
Executable size: 8336 bytes

Ran on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (4 x 1.4Ghz, Arm 6)

If anyone would like to offer code, tips, pointers... I would appreciate it. I will also implement the changes and give a timed result for your troubles.

Oh, and one thing that I learned is to always de-allocate `malloc`; I ran the code above (with extra loops), just before posting this. My computer's ram filled up, and the computer froze. Luckily, Stack made a backup draft! Lesson learned!

*** EDIT ***

Here is the revised code using chqrlie's advice as best I could. Added extra checks for end of string, which ended up costing about a second of time with the tested phrase but can now bail very fast if the first string is not found. Using null or illogical strings should not result in error, hopefully. Lots of notes int the code, where they can be better understood. If I've left anything thing out or done something incorrectly, please let me know guys; it is not intentional.

**fast_strbetween2.c**:

```
/*
   Compile with:
   gcc -Wall -O3 fast_strbetween2.c -o fast_strbetween2

   Corrections and additions courtesy of:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308295/extracting-a-string-between-two-similar-or-different-strings-in-c-as-fast-as-p

*/

#include<stdio.h>  // printf
#include<stdlib.h> // malloc, free

// Strings now set to 'const'
char * fast_strbetween(const char *str, const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    // string size will now be calculated by the characters picked up
    size_t str1pos    = 0;
    size_t str1chars;

    // Find str1
    do{

        str1chars = 0;

        // Will the do/while str1 check for '\0' suffice?
        // I haven't seen any issues yet, but not sure.
        while(str1[str1chars] == str[str1pos + str1chars]  && str1[str1chars] != '\0')
        {
            //printf("Found str1 char: %i num: %i pos: %i\n", str1[str1chars], str1chars + 1, str1pos);

            ++str1chars;
        }

        // Incrementing whilst not in conditional expression tested faster
        ++str1pos;

    /* There are two checks for "str1[str1chars] != '\0'". Trying to find
       another efficient way to do it in one. */
    }while(str[str1pos] != '\0' && str1[str1chars] != '\0');

    --str1pos;

    //For testing:
    //printf("str1pos: %i str1chars: %i\n", str1pos, str1chars);

    // exit if no chars were found or if didn't reach end of str1
    if(!str1chars || str1[str1chars] != '\0')
    {
        //printf("Bailing from str1 result\n");
        return '\0';
    }

    /* Got rid of the '+1' code which didn't allow for '' returns.
       I agree with your logic of <tag></tag> returning ''. */
    size_t str2pos = str1pos + str1chars;
    size_t str2chars;

    //printf("Starting pos for str2: %i\n", str1pos + str1chars);

    // Find str2
    do{

        str2chars = 0;

        while(str2[str2chars] == str[str2pos + str2chars] && str2[str2chars] != '\0')
        {
            //printf("Found str2 char: %i num: %i pos: %i \n", str2[str2chars], str2chars + 1, str2pos);
            ++str2chars;
        }

        ++str2pos;

    }while(str[str2pos] != '\0' && str2[str2chars] != '\0');

    --str2pos;

    //For testing:
    //printf("str2pos: %i str2chars: %i\n", str2pos, str2chars);

    if(!str2chars || str2[str2chars] != '\0')
    {
        //printf("Bailing from str2 result!\n");
        return '\0';
    }

    /* Trying to allocate strbetween with malloc. Is this correct? */
    char * strbetween = malloc(2);

    // Check if malloc succeeded:
    if (strbetween == '\0') return '\0';

    size_t tmp = 0;

    // Grab and store the string between!
    for(size_t i = str1pos + str1chars; i < str2pos; ++i)
    {
        strbetween[tmp] = str[i];
        ++tmp;
    }

    return strbetween;
}

int main() {

    char str[30]  = { "abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb" };
    char str1[10] = { "aaa" };
    char str2[10] = { "bbb" };

    printf("Searching \'%s\' for \'%s\' and \'%s\'\n", str, str1, str2);
    printf("           0123456789\n\n"); // Easily see the elements
    printf("The word between is: \'%s\'\n", fast_strbetween(str, str1, str2));

    for(int i = 10000000; --i;)
        free(fast_strbetween(str, str1, str2));

    return 0;
}
```

** Results **

```
$ time fast_strbetween2                                                 
Searching 'abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb' for 'aaa' and 'bbb'
           0123456789

The word between is: 'abba'
    0m10.93s real     0m10.93s user     0m00.00s system
```

Process used 99.0 - 100% CPU according to 'top' command (Linux).
Memory used while running: 1.8Mb
Executable size: 8336 bytes
Ran on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (4 x 1.4Ghz, Arm 6)

chqrlie's answer

I understand that this is just some example code that shows proper programming practices. Nonetheless, it can make for a decent control in testing.

Please note that I do not know how to deallocate malloc in your code, so it is NOT a fair test. As a result, ram usage builds up, taking 130Mb+ for the process alone. I was still able to run the test for the full 10000000 loops. I will say that I tried deallocating this code the way I did my code (via bringing the function 'simple_strbetween' down into main and deallocating with 'free(strndup(p, q - p));'), and the results weren't much different from not deallocating.

** simple_strbetween.c **

```
/*
   Compile with:
   gcc -Wall -O3 simple_strbetween.c -o simple_strbetween

   Courtesy of:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308295/extracting-a-string-between-two-similar-or-different-strings-in-c-as-fast-as-p

*/

#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

char *simple_strbetween(const char *str, const char *str1, const char *str2) {

    const char *q;
    const char *p = strstr(str, str1);

    if (p) {
        p += strlen(str1);
        q = *str2 ? strstr(p, str2) : p + strlen(p);
        if (q)
            return strndup(p, q - p);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {

    char str[30] =  { "abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb" };
    char str1[10] = { "aaa" };
    char str2[10] = { "bbb" };

    printf("Searching \'%s\' for \'%s\' and \'%s\'\n", str, str1, str2);
    printf("           0123456789\n\n"); // Easily see the elements
    printf("The word between is: \'%s\'\n", simple_strbetween(str, str1, str2));

    for(int i = 10000000; --i;)
        simple_strbetween(str, str1, str2);

    return 0;
}

$ time simple_strbetween                                                
Searching 'abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb' for 'aaa' and 'bbb'
           0123456789

The word between is: 'abba'
    0m19.68s real     0m19.34s user     0m00.32s system
```

Process used 100% CPU according to 'top' command (Linux).
Memory used while running: 130Mb (leak due do my lack of knowledge)
Executable size: 8380 bytes
Ran on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (4 x 1.4Ghz, Arm 6)

Results for above code ran with this alternate strndup:

```
char *alt_strndup(const char *s, size_t n)
{   
    size_t i;
    char *p; 
    for (i = 0; i < n && s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        continue;
    p = malloc(i + 1);
    if (p != NULL) { 
        memcpy(p, s, i);
        p[i] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}

$ time simple_strbetween                                                
Searching 'abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb' for 'aaa' and 'bbb'
           0123456789

The word between is: 'abba'
    0m20.99s real     0m20.54s user     0m00.44s system
```

I kindly ask that nobody make judgements on the results until the code is properly ran. I will revise the results as soon as it is figured out.

*** Edit ***

Was able to decrease the time by over 25% (11.93s vs 8.7s). This was done by using pointers to increment the positions, as opposed to size_t. Collecting the return string whilst checking the last string was likely what caused the biggest change. I feel there is still lots of room for improvement. A big loss comes from having to free malloc. If there is a better way, I'd like to know.

fast_strbetween3.c:

```
/*

 gcc -Wall -O3 fast_strbetween.c -o fast_strbetween

*/

#include<stdio.h>  // printf
#include<stdlib.h> // malloc, free

char * fast_strbetween(const char *str, const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    const char *sbegin = &str1[0];    // String beginning
    const char *spos;

    // Find str1
    do{

        spos = str;
        str1 = sbegin;

        while(*spos == *str1 && *str1)
        {
            ++spos;
            ++str1;
        }

        ++str;

    }while(*str1 && *spos); 

    // Nothing found if spos hasn't advanced
    if (spos == str)
        return NULL;

    char *strbetween = malloc(1);
    if (!strbetween)
        return '\0';

    str = spos;
    int i = 0;
    //char *p = &strbetween[0];   // Alt. for advancing strbetween (slower) 
    sbegin = &str2[0];     // Recycle sbegin

    // Find str2
    do{

        str2 = sbegin;
        spos = str;

        while(*spos == *str2 && *str2)
        {
            ++str2;
            ++spos;
        }

        //*p = *str;
        //++p;

        strbetween[i] = *str;
        ++str;
        ++i;

    }while(*str2 && *spos);

    if (spos == str)
        return NULL;

    //*--p = '\0';

    strbetween[i - 1] = '\0';

    return strbetween;
}

int main() {

    char s[100]  = "abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb";
    char s1[100] = "aaa";
    char s2[100] = "bbb";

    printf("\nString: \'%s\'\n", fast_strbetween(s, s1, s2));

    for(int i = 10000000; --i; )
      free(fast_strbetween(s, s1, s2));

    return 0;
  }
```

String: 'abba'
    0m08.70s real     0m08.67s user     0m00.01s system

Process used 99.0 - 100% CPU according to 'top' command (Linux).
Memory used while running: 1.8Mb
Executable size: 8336 bytes
Ran on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (4 x 1.4Ghz, Arm 6)

*** Edit ***

This doesn't really count as it does not 'return' a value, and therefore is against my own rules, but it does pass a variable through, which is changed and brought back to main. It runs with 1 library and takes 3.6s. Getting rid of malloc was the key.

```
/*

 gcc -Wall -O3 fast_strbetween.c -o fast_strbetween

*/

#include<stdio.h>  // printf

unsigned int fast_strbetween(const char *str, const char *str1, const char *str2, char *strbetween)
{
    const char *sbegin = &str1[0];    // String beginning
    const char *spos;

    // Find str1
    do{

        spos = str;
        str1 = sbegin;

        while(*spos == *str1 && *str1)
        {
            ++spos;
            ++str1;
        }

        ++str;

    }while(*str1 && *spos); 

    // Nothing found if spos hasn't advanced
    if (spos == str)
    {
        strbetween[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }

    str = spos;
    sbegin = &str2[0];     // Recycle sbegin

    // Find str2
    do{

        str2 = sbegin;
        spos = str;

        while(*spos == *str2 && *str2)
        {
            ++str2;
            ++spos;
        }

        *strbetween = *str;
        ++strbetween;
        ++str;

    }while(*str2 && *spos);

    if (spos == str)
    {
        strbetween[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }

    *--strbetween = '\0';

    return 1;  // Successful (found text)
}

int main() {

    char s[100]  = "abaabbbaaaabbabbbaaabbb";
    char s1[100] = "aaa";
    char s2[100] = "bbb";
    char sret[100];

    fast_strbetween(s, s1, s2, sret);
    printf("String: %s\n", sret);

    for(int i = 10000000; --i; )
      fast_strbetween(s, s1, s2, sret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi bedtime.  I don't think there is a clear question here appropriate for stackoverflow.  If you want general feedback or pointers, you may have better luck on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Simple is usually best. `strstr` to find pointer to `str1`, validate, then `strstr (p + 1, str2)`, validate `q - p > 1` and then allocate `q - p + 1` and `memcpy` and nul-terminate.

Comment: MFisherKDX, thanks for the other site. We'll see how this unfolds, and if it comes to it, I'll know where to go. David C. Rankin. Usually, yes. I have to admit that I often micro-focus when it might be better that I just left as is; but, the timed results may speak a different story—'time' will tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems and is probably not as efficient as it should be:

- you use types `int` and `unsigned int` for indexes into the strings. These types may be smaller than the range of `size_t`. You should revise your code to use `size_t` and avoid mixing signed and unsigned types in comparisons.
- your functions' string arguments should be declared as `const char *` as you do not modify the strings and should be able to pass const strings without a warning.
- redefining `strlen` is a bad idea: your version will be slower than the system's optimized, assembly coded and very likely inlined version.
- computing the length of `str` is unnecessary and potentially costly: both `str1` and `str2` may appear close to the beginning of `str`, scanning for the end of `str` will be wasteful.
- the `while` loop inside the first `do` / `while` loop is incorrect: `while(str1[charsfound] == str[str1pos + charsfound]) charsfound++;` may access characters beyond the end of `str` and `str1` as the loop does not stop at the null terminator. If `str1` only appears at the end of `str`, you have undefined behavior.
- if `str1` is an empty string, you will find it at the end of `str` instead of at the beginning.
- why do you initialize `str2pos` as `int str2pos = str1pos + str1len + 1;`? If `str2` immediately follows `str1` inside `str`, an empty string should be allocated and returned. Your comment regarding this case is unreadable, you should break such long lines to fit within a typical screen width such as 80 columns. It is debatable whether `strbetween("aa", "a", "a")` should return `""` or `NULL`. IMHO it should return an allocated empty string, which would be consistent with the expected behavior on `strbetween("<name></name>", "<name>", "</name>")` or `strbetween("''", "'", "'")`. Your specification preventing `strbetween` from returning an empty string produces a counter-intuitive border case.
- the second scanning loop has the same problems as the first.
- the line `char *strbetween = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * str2pos - str1pos - str1len);` has multiple problems: no cast is necessary in C, if you insist on specifying the element size `sizeof(char)`, which is 1 by definition, you should parenthesize the number of elements, and last but not least, you **must** allocate one extra element for the null terminator.
- You do not test if `malloc()` succeeded. If it returns `NULL`, you will have undefined behavior, whereas you should just return `NULL`.
- the copying loop uses a mix of signed and unsigned types, causing potentially counterintuitive behavior on overflow.
- you forget to set the null terminator, which is consistent with the allocation size error, but incorrect.

Before you try and optimize code, you must ensure correctness! Your code is too complicated and has multiple flaws. Optimisation is a moot point.

You should first try a very simple implementation using standard C string functions: searching a string inside another one is performed efficiently by `strstr`.

Here is a simple implementation using `strstr` and `strndup()`, which should be available on your system:

```
#include <string.h>

char *simple_strbetween(const char *str, const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    const char *q;
    const char *p = strstr(str, str1);
    if (p) {
        p += strlen(str1);
        q = *str2 ? strstr(p, str2) : p + strlen(p);
        if (q)
            return strndup(p, q - p);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

`strndup()` is defined in POSIX and is part of the *Extensions to the C Library Part II: Dynamic Allocation Functions, ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010*. If it is not available on your system, it can be redefined as:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    char *p;
    for (i = 0; i < n && s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        continue;
    p = malloc(i + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, i);
        p[i] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

To ensure correctness, write a number of test cases, with border cases such as all combinations of empty strings and identical strings.

Once your have thoroughly your `strbetween` function, you can write a benchmarking framework to test performance. This is not so easy to get reliable performance figures, as you will experience if you try.  Remember to configure your compiler to select the appropriate optimisations, `-O3` for example.

Only then can you move to the next step: if you are really restricted from using standard C library functions, you may first recode your versions of `strstr` and `strlen` and still use the same method. Test this new version both for correctness and for performance.

The redundant parts are the computation of `strlen(str1)` which must have been determined by `strstr` when it finds a match. And the scan in `strndup()` which is unnecessary since no null byte is present between `p` and `q`. If you have time to waste, you can try and remove these redundancies at the expense of readability, risking non conformity. I would be surprised if you get any improvement at all on average over a wide variety of test cases. 20% would be remarkable.

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer. The reasonable case I could think of would be something like `char *p = strstr (str, str1), *q; if (p && (q = strstr (p + 1, str2)) && q - p > 1) /* allocate q - p + 1, memcpy, nul-terminate */`

Comment: chaqrlie, If I could give you 2 upvotes, I would; thank you so much for taking the time to write all this! Very very informative, and just the thing I need be set me on the straight path of code correctness, which I sorely lack ATM... I've made most of the corrections that I could. Not sure if I got the 'malloc' code correct. Comments of fixes are in code. Might take a bit for me to run some extra tests and update the original post. David C. Rankin: I like your optimisations. Could you just add the rest of the code, so I could run it against the others?